# Converting a System.Array to Double() in VB.NET 2012

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I want to convert an array of type `System.Array` to `Double()` or `Double(,)` (I already know which one to convert to). The problematic lines of code follow

```
Dim kernel As Double() = CType(Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Double), _
  {2 * limit + 1}, {-limit}), Double())
```

Where `limit` is predefined as a valid, positive `Integer`. I get the `InvalidCastException`. How do I go about doing this? Or another way of creating a `Double` array with `< 0` starting index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Enumerable.Range` method to create a single-dimension array like so:

```
Dim start = 0
Dim count = 10

Dim singleArray = Enumerable.Range(start, count).ToArray()
```

To create a multidimensional array you will have to create your own extension method to modify the collection as I have done below

```
Public Module Extensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Function SelectMultiDimension(Of T)(collection As IEnumerable(Of T), rows As Integer, cols As Integer) As T(,)
        Dim multiDimArray(rows - 1, cols - 1) As T
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For Each item In collection
            If i >= multiDimArray.Length Then Exit For

            multiDimArray(i \ cols, i Mod cols) = item

            i += 1
        Next

        Return multiDimArray
    End Function
End Module
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
Dim mArray = Enumerable.Range(start, count).SelectMultiDimension(3, 4)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I need an array of the `Double()` or `Double(,)` datatype, not the `Array` datatype. The [`Array.CreateInstance` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx) already does all you have described. I need to do this in order to achieve interoperability with other APIs.